# Is there a program similar to After Effects that lets you animate the points of a polygon according to a mathematical function?

Tags: animation, software-recommendation

I have some irregular polygons defined by points whose coordinates depend on a variable `r`, for example:

```
x = if(1 / sqrt(10) <= r < 1 / sqrt(5)) { 
        -2 r² + r sqrt(1 - r²) - sqrt(2 r⁴ - r² + 2 r sqrt(1 - r²) (2 - 2 r²) - 1) + 2
    } else if(r < 1 / sqrt(10)) { 
        (2 (5 - r²) + r sqrt(5 - r²)) / 5
    }

y = if(1 / sqrt(10) <= r < 1 / sqrt(5)) { 
        (r sqrt(1 - r²)) / (1 - r²) (-2 r² + r sqrt(1 - r²) - sqrt(2 r⁴ - r² + 2 r sqrt(1 - r²) (2 - 2 r²) - 1) + 2)
    } else if(r < 1 / sqrt(10)) {
        ((5 - r²) - 2 r sqrt(5 - r²)) / 5
    }
```

I want to create a high-quality rendered video of the polygons changing shape as `r` varies, but After Effects, my normal go-to for animations, does not allow the user to control the exact positions of the points of shape layers with expressions in the way that I want. Is there an alternative animation program that supports this kind of thing?

Comment: you can do this kind of thing in Blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/how-can-i-generate-an-object-from-a-mathematical-function

Comment: @tomh The linked question appears to be about creating a 3D surface according to an implicit function. It doesn't look like Blender allows defining individual vertex coordinates of a 2D shape with an animating function. Am I missing something?